# Folder structure when Lumen With Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, directory-structure, lumen

I would like to develop web application using `Lumen` and `AngularJs`. I have `app` folder which contains all `angularJS` files,which means client side application inside `app` folder.

But I found two folder for view purpose in `Lumen`,those are `public` and `resource`. all view files pointed out in `resource` folder and all `assets` like `js`,`images` etc are in public folder.

[image]

How can I bring all in to a particular location either public or resource.

Please explain is there any good practice in case of folder structure?

If I using both `public` and `resource` folder,Is it good practice?

Comment: Simply build your back-end using Lumen and your front-end with angularjs. Your angularjs app can work well in the public folder. With regard to routing, make use of the `ngRoute` in Angularjs.

Answer (score 3):

These folders have a different purpose.  The `resources` folder is where your views will go.  Lumen will grab these, perform any necessary functions on them, then display them.

The public folder would be a place where you put your assets (images, css, javascript, etc...).  You should have this folder set as your document root in your webserver.

The views themselves which reside in `resources/views` should not be directly accessible by anyone on the net, the public folder should be.  Although, you probably won't be using this folder much because you are using Angular so most of your html would go in the public folder to be accessed by Angular.

Comment: Thank you for reply,How how can I change my view path to public. Now it is pointing to resource folder?

Comment: Are you using Angular or Lumen for routing?

Comment: angular routing for client side and lumen for API's

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Angular but I believe you'd just put your html files into the public folder then.  Lumen really shouldn't have any idea they exist, all it's responsible for is returning appropriate responses for the ajax requests made by Angular.  In this case, you wouldn't need to modify Lumen's view path because you aren't returning any views, just json.

Comment: First need to load `index.php` view file.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found view path settings in `lumen` on following location,

```
vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/view
```

And change settings from

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views'))
],
```

To

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('public/app'))
],
```

Comment: Just one thing to mention, you cannot make changes to the vendor directory (because it will be overwritten by composer later), they should be overriding these configurations in the app config directory.

Answer (score -1):

I am late to the party but I Totally agree with user3158900

You can find an example structuring for AngularJS and Lumen project at (http://bowyer.colorgap.com), code is available on Github.